# Wrong arraylist output with duplicate result in 2 cicle for

Tags: java, arraylist

```
for(int i = 0; i<listut.size();i+=2){
String query3="select........";
ResultSet rs3= con.createStatement().executeQuery(query3);
while(rs3.next())
{
    idserv= rs3.getString("IDservices");
    nameserv= rs3.getString("Name");
    autorizzato = rs3.getString("Autorizzato");
    listab.add(idserv);
    listab.add(nameserv);
    listab.add(autorizzato);
}}
```

I've a problem with the ouput of arraylist, the result is duplicated, in arraylist listut i've 3 elements.. for each element .
First element:

```
[1, getStructureAgent, 1, 2, searchStructureAgent, 0, 3, getZona, 0, 4, getFido, 0, 5, getCostruttore, 0, 6, searchAgent, 0, 7, getPayment, 0, 8, searchGruppo, 0, 9, getArticolo, 0, 10, searchPayment, 0, 11, searchZona, 0, 12, getGruppo, 0, 13, getCustomers, 0, 14, searchArticolo, 0, 15, getSottoGruppo, 0, 16, getAgent, 0, 17, getCustomer, 0, 18, searchCondizioniBancarieClienteOasi, 0, 19, getArboAnagrafica, 0, 20, getFidoClienteOasi, 0, 21, searchSottoGruppo, 0, 22, searchCostruttore, 0]
```

Second element

```
[1, getStructureAgent, 1, 2, searchStructureAgent, 0, 3, getZona, 0, 4, getFido, 0, 5, getCostruttore, 0, 6, searchAgent, 0, 7, getPayment, 0, 8, searchGruppo, 0, 9, getArticolo, 0, 10, searchPayment, 0, 11, searchZona, 0, 12, getGruppo, 0, 13, getCustomers, 0, 14, searchArticolo, 0, 15, getSottoGruppo, 0, 16, getAgent, 0, 17, getCustomer, 0, 18, searchCondizioniBancarieClienteOasi, 0, 19, getArboAnagrafica, 0, 20, getFidoClienteOasi, 0, 21, searchSottoGruppo, 0, 22, searchCostruttore, 0, 1, getStructureAgent, 1, 2, searchStructureAgent, 0, 3, getZona, 0, 4, getFido, 0, 5, getCostruttore, 0, 6, searchAgent, 0, 7, getPayment, 0, 8, searchGruppo, 0, 9, getArticolo, 0, 10, searchPayment, 0, 11, searchZona, 0, 12, getGruppo, 0, 13, getCustomers, 0, 14, searchArticolo, 0, 15, getSottoGruppo, 0, 16, getAgent, 0, 17, getCustomer, 0, 18, searchCondizioniBancarieClienteOasi, 0, 19, getArboAnagrafica, 0, 20, getFidoClienteOasi, 0, 21, searchSottoGruppo, 0, 22, searchCostruttore, 0]
```

In the second cicle the array contains result of first cicle

Comment: and what did you expect as output? did you debug your code?

Comment: I expect an array list which has the same size as the first one

Comment: Where do you initialize `listab`?  What do you initialize it to?

Comment: @Stultuske there is a way to clean the resulset?

Comment: it's most likely listab you should clean

Comment: @ScottHunter I initialize it outside the for cycle

Comment: @Stultuske yes i think i should clean listab

Comment: ArrayList<String> listab = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `listab` to start each iteration of the for loop being empty, you need to make it empty at the top of the body of that loop.